# How Can i Force A page to be hidden from direct access and can only be accessed from paypal redirect?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway

Can someone please help me?
as the title say, i have an order page on that order the user buy using paypal,
once the payment is completed the user is redirected to form.php.
My problem is that i can access directly form.php!!
How can i make it only accessible from paypal successful payment?
i know i have to use IPN or DPT but what should i write in my form.php so i can check that the payment is successful and the user can access this page?
Please guys I need your help!
Can anyone write this missing code?

Comment: what is return url and IPN url ?

Comment: you can't. if it's on your webserver, it's accessible. at best you can restrict access by user/pass, and/or ugly/obfuscated url path

Comment: it can be possible just need a hack

Answer (score 1):

There is no method of verifying the payment has been made by a simple redirect. You "could" check the referrer, but this can be easily spoofed.

For a rock solid verification, you would need to use Paypal's IPN.

Answer (score 0):

- In your `SetExpressCheckout` call add some unique and expiring variable(s) that you can treat as an "expiring session" in your `ReturnUrl` (or even use a Session if that suits your needs).
- Paypal will echo those variable(s) back to you when they redirect (along with the expected `token` and `payerid`)
- Validate the "expiring session" variable in your `ReturnUrl`

  - if invalid/not present, handle as you deem appropriate (e.g. redirect somewhere, error message, etc.)

So in essence, you'd only make the page "accessible" if the request for it is "valid" (according to how you define "valid").

Hth...